# Filter data in d3 to draw either circle or square

Tags: d3.js

I'm having a bit of trouble understand selections and filtering in d3. Let's say I have a simple array:

```
data = [1, 2, 6, 3, 4]
```

I want to draw circles if the value < 5 and squares if it's  >= 5. My code right now only draws circles and looks like this:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
svg.selectAll("shapes")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
```

and other attributes for circles. I need to use the `.filter()` method, but I don't know where to put it. I tried doing something like:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
svg.selectAll("shapes")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .filter(function(d){if (d>5){console.log('working');})
    .append("circle")
```

but then I get an error with the `append` method. Can someone point me in the right direction on how I'd accomplish this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that after you `.enter()` you are returning a nested array, hence your error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'append'

To use `.filter()`, you need to apply it *after* the `.append()`:

```
var data = d3.range(10);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var shapes = svg.selectAll(".shapes")
    .data(data).enter();

shapes.append("circle")
    .filter(function(d){ return d < 5; })
    .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return (i+1) * 25; })
    .attr("cy", 10)
    .attr("r", 10);

shapes.append("rect")
    .filter(function(d){ return d >= 5; })
    .attr("x", function(d, i){ return (i+1) * 25; })
    .attr("y", 25)
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10);
```

Using the code above (also in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/txAqx/1/)), I get the following output:

[image]

Note that you can also achieve the same effect using [Array's filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), e.g.

```
var shapes = svg.selectAll(".shapes")
    .data(data.filter(function(d){ return d < 5; })).enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return (i+1) * 25; })
    .attr("cy", 10)
    .attr("r", 10);
```

Comment: This is perfect! I didn't quite understand that you use .filter() directly on the data itself.

Comment: @ukejoe: using Array's `filter` method is one way to filter the data beforehand is one way, but I actually prefer what you were trying to do with d3's `filter`. Please see my updated answer!

Comment: Aha! So with d3's filter you pull in the data first by calling .enter() and then filter based off that.

Comment: @mdml: Your original answer using `selection.filter()` leaves a bunch of empty circles and squares. Another option is to filter on the items you _don't_ want and then `.remove()` them: http://jsfiddle.net/LGJNF/1/

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the tip of remove() to get rid of the empty circles. It is interesting that this works only if you put filter as the last call of the chain. Also, when I move filter from after append to the last call, I had to reverse the return value. Furthermore, putting the filter as the last call in chain would have no effect if there is not remove.

Answer (score 6):

It is also possible use the data to conditionally create circles or rectangles by providing a function argument to the [append function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#append)

```
    .append(function(d, i){
        if (something to do with d) {
            ... return an SVG circle element
        } else {
            ... return an SVG rectangle element
        }
    })
```

e.g. like this

```
var data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

function createSvgEl(name) {
    return document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', name);
}

svg
    .selectAll(".shapes")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append(function(d, i){
        if (d <= 4) {
            return createSvgEl("circle");
        } else {
            return createSvgEl("rect");
        }
    });

svg.selectAll("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return (i+1) * 25; })
        .attr("cy", 10)
        .attr("r", 10);

svg.selectAll("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i){ return (i+1) * 25; })
        .attr("y", 25)
        .attr("width", 10)
        .attr("height", 10);
```