# Get one element from d3js selection, by index

Tags: d3.js

I've created a set of d3js elements based on an array of 3 elements:

```
var data = [[0,0,2],[0,23,5],[2,12,5]];
circleSet = svg.selectAll()
             .data(data)
             .enter().append('circle');
```

edit:

How can I select the second element by index?

Comment: Assuming that these are the only circles in your SVG, you could do `d3.select("circle:nth-child(2)")`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The most natural way to manipulate just one element is using the filter function:

```
var data = [[0,0,2],[0,23,5],[2,12,5]];
var circleSet = svg.selectAll()
         .data(data)
         .enter()
         .append('circle');
var filteredCircleSet = circleSet
         .filter(function (d, i) { return i === 1;})
         // put all your operations on the second element, e.g.
         .append('h1').text('foo');
```

Note that depending on what you do with the other elements you might use one of the two variants of this approach:

- variant a): use the filter in the data function (to reduce the data and the appended elements)
- variant b): use the filter to exclude instead of to include in order to remove the other elements at the end

See also [Filter data in d3 to draw either circle or square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335118/filter-data-in-d3-to-draw-either-circle-or-square)

One other way to do it is to use the selection.each method: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-each
By using an if statement with the corresponding index you can create a block for one element. 
E.g.

```
var data = [[0,0,2],[0,23,5],[2,12,5]];
var circleSet = svg.selectAll()
         .data(data)
         .enter()
         .append('circle')
         .each(function (d, i) {
            if (i === 1) {
              // put all your operations on the second element, e.g.
              d3.select(this).append('h1').text(i);    
            }
          });
```

Comment: Be careful with code readability when changing the selection mid-chain like this: for example in your first example, the variable `circleSet` is the single item, not the full set. If you do it this way, `var circleSet = d3.select()...append('something'); var secondCircle = circleSet.filter(...)` is probably clearer.

Answer (score 23):

In d3 v4 and above, you can use [`Selection.nodes()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_nodes). Assuming `i` is the index number you want:

```
d3.select(someSelection.nodes()[i])
```

It's a natural one-liner, and it's arguably more readable: you're obviously just getting the node at `i` in the order, as a D3 selection.

---

It *looks* like it'd be more efficient than the alternatives, which involve looping through the entire selection with `.each()`. So, you might think this is *[O(1)](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/)*, while the other options are *O(n)*.

Unfortunately, Selection.nodes() itself includes an `each` loop, so it's also *O(n)* (not that it's likely to matter in real life unless you call this thousands of times on selections with thousands of nodes):

```
var nodes = new Array(this.size()), i = -1;
this.each(function() { nodes[++i] = this; });
return nodes;
```

However, this way you can separate the looping from the getting, which could be useful if efficiency is a major concern.

For example, if you want to loop through `each()` in selection A and get the item in the same position from selection B, and you want to avoid loops-within-loops because those selections can be huge and you call this many times, you could structure it like this, which would be *O(2n)* instead of *O(n^2)*:

```
var selectionBArray = selectionB.nodes()

selectionA.each(function(d, i) {
  var iFromSelectionA = this
  var iFromSelectionB = d3.select(selectionBArray[i])
})
```

...or if you're using arrow functions to preserve `this` context:

```
var selectionBArray = selectionB.nodes()

selectionA.each((d, i, nodes) => {
  var iFromSelectionA = d3.select(nodes[i])
  var iFromSelectionB = d3.select(selectionBArray[i])
})
```

---

You could even (ab)use `Selection._groups`, but I wouldn't recommend using a private property like that since it'll break if a D3 update renamed the `_groups` property, [like this update did](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/commit/0627356a10749541755434bcfac62b57140cb881).

Answer (score 7):

Use the preset function `i` variable, which references the index of the array object.

```
var data = [[0,0,2],[0,23,5],[2,12,5]];
circleSet = svg.selectAll()
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append('circle')
     .attr('fill',function(d,i){i === 1 ? return 'red' : return 'black' };
```

Find more on array structure references in d3.js [at this tutorial](https://www.dashingd3js.com/data-structures-d3js-accepts)

You can also encode each element you append by utilizing the count of the `i` index when assigning a class.

```
var data = [[0,0,2],[0,23,5],[2,12,5]];
    circleSet = svg.selectAll()
         .data(data)
         .enter()
         .append('circle')
         .attr("class",function(d,i){ return "yourclass item" + i })

var theSecondElement = d3.select(".item1")
```

Last, you could use the .each method and a conditional to target a specific element

```
circleSet = svg.selectAll()
         .data(data)
         .enter()
         .append('circle')
         .each(function (d, i) {
            if (i === 1) {
              var that = this;
              (function textAdd() {
                 d3.select(that).append('h1').text(i); 
              )();   
            }
          });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've edited my answer to ask, how can I simply select the second element so that I can manipulate it in any way I want? Already given you an upvote.

Comment: you just use ....enter().append('circle').each(function (d, i) { if (i === 1) { // here you put all the operations on your second element});

Comment: e.g. inside the block you put d3.select(this).append('h1').text(i);

Comment: I have updated my answer with a strategy to solve the question you posed.

Comment: In code veritas: Thanks man. I actually used your strategy with the classes to solve my problem.

Comment: @ee2Dev Hey man, your answer is the most efficient, if you post it up I will upvote and give you accepted answer.

Comment: Does .each run more quickly? I try and avoid it.

Comment: Rich: I posted my answer to show an alternative way. As in the answer of In code veritas, you end up with a selection containing exactly your element. Then you can do anything with it.

Comment: @incodeveritas: Would have to run it on jsperf.com, but I would assume it will be faster than assigning a class to each one and then selecting by class.

Comment: I am just adding one more approach which seems the most natural to your question: just use the filter function to select your element(s). In comparison with the other answers you can bypass creating classes or calling the each function. I have prepended this approach to my answer. Good luck with your work!