# Filtering data to conditionally render elements

Tags: d3.js

I have come across this SO - [Filter data in d3 to draw either circle or square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335118/filter-data-in-d3-to-draw-either-circle-or-square)

Which is what I'm following to attempt to conditionally render some text elements if a certain data property is present.

The problem is that the accepted answer on the above post results in empty elements being added since the filter is being called after the append.

I am trying to filter the data before the append call is made like so:

```
layers.selectAll('text')
    .data(function(d) {
        return d.dataPointValues;
    })
    .filter(function(d){
        return angular.isDefined(d.pointLabel);
    })
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.pointLabel;
    })
    .attr('x', function(d) {
        return x(d.pointKey) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
        return y(d.y0 + d.pointValue) - 5;
    })
    .attr('class', 'data-value');
```

But I get back an error from d3:

> TypeError: layers.selectAll(...).data(...).filter(...).enter is not a
>   function

How can I get only the necessary number of text elements appended using a filter, or should I be using a different approach here?

Comment: What about filtering your data before binding it? You could do something like `.data(function (d) { return d.dataPointValues.filter(function (v) { return angular.isDefined(v.pointLabel); }); })`. This uses the standard JS `Array.prototype.filter()` method.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Ok thanks, I will bear this in mind for future questions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try applying the filter on the data inside the data function like this

```
layers.selectAll('text')
.data(function(d){d.dataPointValues.filter(function(dp){ return angular.isDefined(dp.pointLabel); }})
.enter()
.append('text')
.text(function(d) {
    return d.pointLabel;
})
.attr('x', function(d) {
    return x(d.pointKey) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
})
.attr('y', function(d) {
    return y(d.y0 + d.pointValue) - 5;
})
.attr('class', 'data-value');
```

Comment: @mindparse Have you really tried this before accepting it? The way it is written now, it is most probably wrong. The first `d` in the call to `data()` is either undefined or referring to some other value from an outer scope. I guess, it should be put inside a callback like mentioned in my [comment](/q/36405450/#comment60427593_36405450) to your question.

Comment: @altocumulus , you are right, i missed the callback initially. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is borking because d3's selection.filter doesn't consider or preserve the selection's enter or exit properties, which you're trying to chain to next - plus with no existing elements the filter will be empty before you hit that error anyways.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/selection/filter.js

You need to append the elements first, which in practical terms means d3's selection.filter is suited for filtering to cherry-pick existing elements for certain styling/transitions etc, rather than to decide whether they get added to the DOM or not in the first place. e.g. the below script would draw nodes in red where its pointValue is > 5, but they would all be added.

```
.enter()
.append('text')
.text(function(d) {
    return d.pointLabel;
})
.filter(function(d){
    return d.pointValue > 5;
})
.style ("stroke", "red");
```

So as the other answer says filter the actual data if it's to decide whether data points should be visualised or not.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation