# D3JS Scatter plots refresh speed

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot

I was wondering if there is a way to change the Scatter plots refresh speed?
As you can see in this [link](http://cpcvip.com/test1/index1.html) the scatter plots gets updated but the time gap between the appearance and disappearance is unreasonable, it look like they are flashing dots.... I tried moving the circle.remove() function right above the circle.transition but it makes no difference.

Below is the relevant code of the refresh function.  Thanks!

```
function updateData() {

    // Get the data again
    data = d3.json("2301data.php", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.dtg = parseDate(d.dtg);
        d.temperature = +d.temperature;
       // d.hum = +d.hum; // Addon 9 part 3
    });

     // Scale the range of the data again 
     x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.dtg; }));
     y.domain([0, 60]);             

    var svg = d3.select("#chart1").select("svg").select("g");

                svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
            .transition()
            .duration(750)
            .call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
            .transition()
            .duration(750)
            .call(yAxis);
        svg.select(".line")   // change the line
            .transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline(data));

    var circle = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);

    circle.remove() //remove old dots   

    // enter new circles
        circle.enter()
            .append("circle")
            .filter(function(d) { return d.temperature > 35 })
            .style("fill", "red")   
            .attr("r", 3.5) 
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.dtg); })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.temperature); })

        // Tooltip stuff after this
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()
                .duration(500)  
                .style("opacity", 0);
            div.transition()
                .duration(200)  
                .style("opacity", .9);  
            div .html(
                d.temperature + "C" + "<br>" +
                formatTime(d.dtg)) 
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 8) + "px")          
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 18) + "px");})
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
            });

    circle.transition().attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.dtg); });   
        // exit 
        circle.exit();



    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your example as it runs, you appear to have loads more circles in the dom than are visible. This is because you add circles for all the data, but then only give positions to those that meet the filter criteria you set.

There was a related question the other day about data filtering versus d3 filtering - [Filtering data to conditionally render elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405450/filtering-data-to-conditionally-render-elements/) . Use data filtering if you don't want to add something full stop, use d3.filter if you want to isolate some elements for special treatment (transitions, different styling etc).

At the moment you're filtering the d3 selection once all the circles are added, but in your case I'd suggest filtering the data before it gets to that stage is best (and as suggested by others in that other question). This may make it run faster (but you're also at the mercy of db updates by the look of your example?)

```
data = data.filter (function(d) { return d.temperature > 35; }); // do filtering here
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);

circle.exit().remove() //remove old dots   

// enter new circles
    circle.enter()
        .append("circle")
        .style("fill", "red")   
        .attr("r", 3.5) 
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.dtg); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.temperature); })
        ...
```

PS. It's a bit confusing what you're trying to do with the circle.remove() and circle.exit(). circle.remove() will remove all existing circles (even ones that exist and have new data), circle.exit() at the end will then have no effect. I'd just have circle.exit().remove() to replace the two calls you make.

Also, without a key function  - https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/ - on your .data() call, you may find dots move around a bit. If your data points have ids, use them.

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data, function(d) { return d.id; /* or d.dtg+" "+d.temperature; if no id property */});
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. 

Filtering the data beforehand is a great idea. 
I tried changing the code, however, as it can be seen at [http://cpcvip.com/test1/index2.html] now after refresh the circles do not appear at all. I posted the code on Fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/badatz/0voh3yke] but due to the active content it's not really working... Any ideas?

Comment: 1. Are you sure you actually have an .id property to key on for .data()? Looking at the database queries appearing under the chart it appears you don't have. In that case fall back to concatenating .dtg and .temperature as a key.

Comment: 2. In general I'd try and merge your original data call and your update call as much as possible. Apart from building the graph axes they're doing the same thing - getting data and plotting it - it's what d3 is good at, add new data, update existing data, take away missing data. But leave that for when you get it working as it is currently.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mgraham the problem was solved.! Below is the revised code in case someone else needs it.

```
function updateData() {

    // Get the data again
    data = d3.json("data.php", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.dtg = parseDate(d.dtg);
        d.temperature = +d.temperature;
      });

       // Scale the range of the data again 
     x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.dtg; }));
     y.domain([0, 60]); // Addon 9 part 4

    var svg = d3.select("#chart1").select("svg").select("g");

    svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
            .transition()
            .duration(750)
            .call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
            .transition()
            .duration(750)
            .call(yAxis);
        svg.select(".line")   // change the line
            .transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline(data));


    data = data.filter (function(d) { return d.temperature > 35; }); 

    var circle = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data, function(d) { return d.dtg+" "+d.temperature;});
    circle.exit().remove() //remove old dots   

    // enter new circles
        circle.enter()
             .append("circle")
         .style("fill", "red")  
         .attr("r", 3.5)    
             .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.dtg); })
         .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.temperature); })

    // Tooltip stuff after this
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()
                .duration(500)  
                .style("opacity", 0);
            div.transition()
                .duration(200)  
                .style("opacity", .9);  
            div .html(
                d.temperature + "C" + "<br>" +
                formatTime(d.dtg)) 
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 8) + "px")          
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 18) + "px");})
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
            });

    circle.transition().attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.dtg); });   


    });
}         

</script>
```