# D3 Scatterplot from all circles to different shapes

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, scatter-plot

I am trying to learn D3 and am looking at this example:

http://bl.ocks.org/weiglemc/6185069

What I want to do now is change the shape of the dots, so I want circles, squares, and triangles based on the brand of the cereal in the data set instead of all circles as datapoints. This seems like it should be a simple change, but I can't get the shapes to show up when I make my change.

I know that this change needs to be made in this segment of the code:

```
  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 3.5)
      .attr("cx", xMap)
      .attr("cy", yMap)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(cValue(d));}) 
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(200)
               .style("opacity", .9);
          tooltip.html(d["Cereal Name"] + "<br/> (" + xValue(d) 
            + ", " + yValue(d) + ")")
               .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
               .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(500)
               .style("opacity", 0);
      });
```

I need to change the append of the circle and the attributes. I want to use a conditional so

```
    .attr("d", function(d,i) {if (d["Cereal Name"] == "Nabisco" return d3.svg.symbol().type("circle"); 
else if (d["Cereal Name"] == "Post" return d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-down"); 
else return d3.svg.symbol().type("circle")
```

However, this is not working for me. Does anyone have an insight in how to do this? I don't want to have all circles, I want different shapes depending on the brand name of the cereal in the example. Thank you.

**Edit:** I tried looking at this:

[Filter data in d3 to draw either circle or square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335118/filter-data-in-d3-to-draw-either-circle-or-square)

But I couldn't get this to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have to set the `symbol` generator (in d3 v4.x):

```
var symbol = d3.symbol();
```

And then appending a `path` element:

```
var dots = svg.selectAll(".dots")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path");
```

After that, it comes the most important part: you have to specify the `type` of your symbol generator. In the following demo, we can set the shape depending on the `name` of the brand (I'm using a dataset about chocolate that i found online):

```
dots.attr("d", symbol.type(function(d){
    if(d.name == "Lindt"){ return d3.symbolCross
    } else if (d.name == "Bournville"){ return d3.symbolDiamond
    } else if (d.name == "Dolfin"){ return d3.symbolSquare
    } else if (d.name == "Hershey"){ return d3.symbolStar
    } else if (d.name == "Galaxy"){ return d3.symbolTriangle
    } else if (d.name == "Dairy Milk"){ return d3.symbolCircle
}}))
```

Of course, you could avoid that ugly bunch of `if...else` defining the symbol type in the dataset itself, or just using an ordinal scale.

Check the working demo (using `manufacturer` instead, to have fewer shapes):

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "Dairy Milk",
        "manufacturer": "cadbury",
        "price": 45,
        "rating": 2
}, {
    "name": "Galaxy",
        "manufacturer": "Nestle",
        "price": 42,
        "rating": 3
}, {
    "name": "Lindt",
        "manufacturer": "Lindt",
        "price": 80,
        "rating": 4
}, {
    "name": "Hershey",
        "manufacturer": "Hershey",
        "price": 40,
        "rating": 1
}, {
    "name": "Dolfin",
        "manufacturer": "Lindt",
        "price": 90,
        "rating": 5
}, {
    "name": "Bournville",
        "manufacturer": "cadbury",
        "price": 70,
        "rating": 2
}];

var w = 300, h = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);
    
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.price})]).range([30,w*0.9]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.rating})*1.1, 0]).range([10,h*0.9]);

var symbol = d3.symbol();

var dots = svg.selectAll(".dots")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path");
    
dots.attr("d", symbol.type(function(d){if(d.manufacturer == "Lindt"){ return d3.symbolCross} else if (d.manufacturer == "cadbury"){ return d3.symbolDiamond} else if (d.manufacturer == "Nestle"){ return d3.symbolSquare} else if (d.manufacturer == "Hershey"){ return d3.symbolStar} }))
    .attr('fill', "teal")
    .attr('stroke','#000')
    .attr('stroke-width',1)
    .attr('transform',function(d){ return "translate("+xScale(d.price)+","+yScale(d.rating)+")"; });

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .call(xAxis)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + w*0.9 + ")");

var gY = svg.append("g")
  .call(yAxis)
  .attr("transform", "translate(30,0)");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm still confused as to how 

svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 3.5)
      .attr("cx", xMap)
      .attr("cy", yMap)

can be changed. This is the main portion I want to change to reflect what you have done. Can I place what you have done after .enter()?

Comment: For using d3.symbol you have to append paths, not circles. And paths are not positioned using x, y, cx or cy. Take that code in your link and create a working Plunker/fiddle/whatever and I'll change it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much Gerardo: https://plnkr.co/edit/BGJvgGIsPNCWX0d2iXYN?p=preview

Comment: I now just can't get the axis to render. The dots look like they are not in the proper spot. I am trying xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom"); and yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");

Comment: Is it possible for you to edit the code snippet with the axis and I can try it on my example? I still can't get the axis to show up, I keep getting TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'd3.svg.axis')

Comment: Do you know why the labels don't show up using D3 V3? The syntax seems the same, but they won't render

Comment: Regarding your other questions: here at SO we deal with one problem at a time, that is, one problem per question. If you have another issues, please post another question. Also, it's a nice idea to accept/upvote an answer if it was useful. It's not compulsory, but it makes people in the community more inclined to help you in the next time you ask. For instance, I simply mentally block people that doesn't accept/upvote answers.

Comment: @Mr.Roboto here is your plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/7eaWpT0iVOeTj7YeshyF?p=preview