# javascript d3 create datasets from one set of data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array of objects and what i want to do is seperate entries based on if a value equals something. I'm reading my data off of a csv and changing some string into ints like this

```
d3.csv('mydata.csv', function(error, data){

  data.forEach(function(d){

d["Fruits"] = +d["Fruits"]
d["Stores"] = +d["Stores"]
d["Names of Fruits"] = d["Names of Fruits"]

});
});
```

This is how my original data looks. mydata

```
Array(10) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
```

The objects looks like this

```
"Fruits": 5
"Stores": 22
"Names of Fruits": "oranges",

"Fruits": 100
"Stores": 3
"Names of Fruits": "apples",


"Fruits": 10
"Stores": 300
"Names of Fruits": "pear",

"Fruits": 10
"Stores": 300
"Names of Fruits": "apple",
```

etc etc.
to get this data i can call console.log(data) and all the above will show up in the console. I want to be able to separate these based on "Names of Fruits" values. so potentially would want to call console.log(appleData) and the results will be

```
 "Fruits": 100
"Stores": 3
"Names of Fruits": "apples",

"Fruits": 10
"Stores": 300
"Names of Fruits": "apple",
```

same with orangeData, pearData etc etc

In order to do this i have tried

```
 d3.csv('mydata.csv', function(error, data){

  appleData = data.forEach(function(d){

    if(d["Names of Fruits"] =="apple"){

      d["Fruits"] = +d["Fruits"]
      d["Stores"] = +d["Stores"]
      d["Names of Fruits"] = d["Names of Fruits"]

  }
 });

    orangeData = data.forEach(function(d){

    if(d["Names of Fruits"] =="orange"){

      d["Fruits"] = +d["Fruits"]
      d["Stores"] = +d["Stores"]
      d["Names of Fruits"] = d["Names of Fruits"]

  }
 });

});
```

​​

​​

Comment: have a look at `d3.nest`

Comment: I think you should take a look at either d3.filter or JavaScripts array.filter. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/20335299

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this; here's a couple examples.  The first uses [d3.nest](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#nests) and turns the data into an array of arrays with the outer key being the name of the fruit.  The second is a little hand-rolled code, which returns an object with properties of each fruit.  What works best really depends on your larger use case.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
    var data = [{
        "Fruits": 5,
        "Stores": 22,
        "Names of Fruits": "oranges"
      }, {
        "Fruits": 100,
        "Stores": 3,
        "Names of Fruits": "apple"
      },
      {
        "Fruits": 10,
        "Stores": 300,
        "Names of Fruits": "pear"
      },

      {
        "Fruits": 10,
        "Stores": 300,
        "Names of Fruits": "apple"
      }
    ];
    
    console.log(
      d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d["Names of Fruits"]; })
        .entries(data)
    );
    
    var rv = {};
    data.forEach(function(d){
      if (!rv[d["Names of Fruits"]]) rv[d["Names of Fruits"]] = [];
      rv[d["Names of Fruits"]].push(d);
    });
    console.log(rv);
      
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```